# <apex:inputfield> in visualforce page is not visible in community sites

Tags: apex, community, site.com

I am having a visual force which is having StandardController and as well as Extension with some  on page.When i executed same VF page in SFDC it's working fine.But when I'm executing same page in Sites it's not showing  values.

The portal user is having **Partner Community User** profile,which is a standard profile we can't change the settings So,I have created a permission set and assigned to all portal user.I have given all field level and object level permssion but still it's not working.I tried with  but still it's not getting rendered.

Comment: i think you need to double check the field level security. Also confirm if other fields of same object are visible or not.

Comment: Nothing is coming.. I have given at all places but still it's not coming

Comment: Have you checked the public settings of site? I assume your VF page runs as site guest user and he doesn't have FLS.

Comment: Setup logs and verify for any error mostly it should be related to field level access